# How to setup UICollectionViewCell margins correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, border, margins

I'm setting up a new prototype for a project, and I need to use a UICollectionView. The thing is, I'm struggling trying to set the correct margins to my UICollectionViewCell, but it doesn't work the way I want.

Here is my problem. I have a UICollectionView showing 3 cells. I'm showing only one cell in every "page". The orientation is horizontal and I'm using pagination as well.

The problem is the last cell. What I need to do to show the right margin of the last (third) cell.

Here's the image. The first one and second one are fine. The third is has a problem.

[image]

I'm subclassing the UICollectionViewCell. I don't thing that's the problem, though.

Here's the UICollectionView configuration and settings.

[image]
[image]

The UICollectionView is a 280x280 square. And the UICollecitonViewCell is a 260x260 square.

Here's the UICollectionViewCell configuration.

[image]

No extra code to change UICollectionView or UICollectionViewCell dimensions. I', trying to do the whole thing using Storyboard.

Any advice?

Thank!

Answer (score 2):

Well.. After testing again, and again, and again I realised how UICollectionView and UICollectionViewCell work.

In my above set up, I make 2 big mistakes.

1) In the UICollectionViewCell setup, I set Custom size. I changed to default instead.

[image]

2) In the "Section Insets", I changed the right value to 10.

[image]

Here's the final result.

[image: It worked!]

:)